# How can I access the WASM memory of an externally loaded page through a C++ Node Module in Electron

Tags: javascript, c++, memory, electron, webassembly

As the title suggests, I am trying to access the WebAssembly (WASM) memory of an externally loaded page (via loadUrl()) from Electron using a C++ Node Module, specifically for read/write operations.

I'm unsure whether to use v8, NAPI, or Nan for this purpose, and I'm uncertain about the process involved.

I had attempted to access it through Electron's preload, and additionally, I tried performing an AOB scan in the browser process within the C++ module.